# JQUERY unable to read value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and I want the click event to read the value of one of the preceding HTML elements. My HTML is

```
<div class="product_list_buy">
   <div class="product_quantity">
      <label for="qty">Qty:</label>
      <input class="quantity" type="text" value="1">
   </div>
   <div class="addcart_wrapper">
       <input class="product_id" type="hidden" value="5666" name="product_id">
       <button class="btn-cart">
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to read the value of quantity element by the following JQUERY:

```
jq('.storelist').unbind('click').on('click',".btn-cart",function(){
var product_qty = jq(this).closest("div").prev(".quantity").val();
.....});
```

But its not able to read the value of .quantity element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `jq(this)` exactly? the `<button>`?

Comment: yes... its the button

Comment: $(this).parents(".product_list_buy").find(".quantity").val(); but I think you should add another div ex. "product_list_item" with product_quantity and addcart_wrapper

Comment: Isn't `.prev('.quantity')` supposed to look for elements with the same "father"? You probably want to use `.prev('.product_quantity')` and then look at their **children** for `.quantity` and get its value. Not complete sure, but try it.

Comment: You should elaborate why you don't just give the input field with class "quantity" an ID an use that to get the elements value. From the description that you provided it ist not clear why. Getting the value of that field by traversing up and down the DOM like that isn't very performant so you should explain why you have to do it in this way.

Comment: i am not able to give an id because the input tag is being generated dynamically by a json output and i dont want to touch that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/bn7ag8j6/

```
var product_qty = $(this).closest("div").prev(".product_quantity").find(".quantity").val();
```

**jQuery `.prev`** ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/prev/))

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .prev() method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that can be passed to the $() function. If the selector is supplied,
>   the preceding element will be filtered by testing whether it match the
>   selector.

In your case, the predecessor of `<div class="addcart_wrapper">` was `<div class="product_quantity">` and you were using the selector `".quantity"`, so it didn't match, and returned an empty jQuery object.

What you should use is `.prev(".product_quantity")` to select `<div class="product_quantity">` and then `.find(".quantity")` to select the input.

Comment: thanks Diego ... worked... and thanks for explaining as well

Answer (score 1):

Consider using your classes from the highest object in the dom:

```
var product_qty = $(this).closest(".product_list_buy").find(".quantity").val();
```